# Docker mongos: provide config server on environment variables

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've deployed a sharded mongodb cluster for development with one shard and one config server.

Into my application stack I need to deploy a `mongos` in order to connect to config server. Related snippet code `docker-compose.yml`:

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6
    command: mongos --configdb cfgrs/cfg1:27017 --bind_ip_all
    ports:
    - 27078:27017
    networks:
      - services-net
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

As you can see at `--configdb cfgrs/cfg1:27017`, config server location is provided in a hard-written way.

I'd like to provide this information using an environment variable.

How could I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `.env` file for this (cf. the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)).

.env

```
CONFIG_SERVER_LOCATION=cfgrs/cfg1:27017
```

docker-compose.yml

```
mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6
    command: mongos --configdb $CONFIG_SERVER_LOCATION --bind_ip_all
    ports:
    - 27078:27017
    networks:
      - services-net
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

Comment: Is it valid using docker swarm?

Comment: The .env file is a feature of docker-compose, so I guess so. But haven't tried it out.